# Almost getting the original text with different IVs, is it normal?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes, cbc-mode

Is it normal that when decrypting AES-encoded encrypted text in CBC mode with an initialization vector different from the original, you get almost the original text?

I am attaching a complete example code, I did not create it but I took it from an online tutorial, I just modified the main to explain better and with an example what I mean:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    private static final String key = "aesEncryptionKey";
    private static String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));

            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalString = "password";
        System.out.println("Original String to encrypt - " + originalString);
        String encryptedString = encrypt(originalString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - " + encryptedString);

        String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("Decrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - " + decryptedString);
        //output: "password"

        initVector = "dncryftionIntVec";
        String decryptedString2 = decrypt(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("Decrypted String with initVector: 'dncryftionIntVec' - " + decryptedString2);
        //output: "qasswyrd"

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original String to encrypt - password
Encrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - AIDTAIiCazaQavILI07rtA==
Decrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - password
Decrypted String with initVector: 'dncryftionIntVec' - qasswyrd
```

Comment: The IV doesn't have to be secret but only unpredictable as Maarten pointed out. Usually, we generate a purely random IV for each encryption and prepend the IV to the ciphertext. When decrypting the first 16 bytes (for AES) can be sliced off to use as the IV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The ciphertext block is first block decrypted and then XOR'ed with the last ciphertext block *or the IV if it is the first ciphertext block*.

So if you look at the first character (characters in ASCII):

Difference in the init vector:

```
'e' ^ 'd' = 65h ^ 64h = 0110_0101b ^ 0110_0100b = 0000_0001b
```

Difference XOR'ed with the plaintext character:

```
'p' ^ 0000_0001b = 70h ^ 0000_0001b = 0111_0000b ^ 0000_0001b = 0111_0001b = 71h = 'q'
```

CBC has limited so called error propagation. Authenticated encryption such as AES-GCM should be preferred in most situations.

Note that CBC mode requires a unpredictable IV, which means basically that it should consist of (pseudo)random bytes.

Answer (score 3):

To make it worse and to underline why @Maarten Bodewes wrote "CBC has limited so called error correction, which is one reason why it should not be preferred over authenticated encryption such as AES-GCM in most situations" see my example that is based on your code.

Think of an (encrypted) payment order that is sent in an email "Send 1000$ to Maarten and Artjom". The attacker gets
access to the initVector (as @Artjom B. wrote it is usually prepended to the ciphertext) and for AES it is 16 bytes long.
The attacker just guesses what the first 16 characters of the order are (because you use this string for every payment...)
and changes the initVector with these simple xor'ing (here I'm changing the initVector-string, in real I would change
the first 16 bytes of the message). **Once again: the attacker has no access to the encryption key.**

```
// here the attacker changes the initVector without knowledge of the encryptionKey
String guessedOrder = "Send 1000$ to Ma";
String newOrder = "Send 9876$ to Ma";
byte[] initvectorOrgByte = "encryptionIntVec".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] initvectorByte = new byte[initvectorOrgByte.length];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    initvectorByte[i] = (byte) (initvectorOrgByte[i] ^ newOrder.getBytes("UTF-8")[i]
      ^ guessedOrder.getBytes("UTF-8")[i]);
}
initVector = new String(initvectorByte);
```

This is the result of decryption with the changed initVector:

```
Original String to encrypt - Send 1000$ to Maarten and Artjom
Encrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - 8raVjEwVYjYaKYcNihWD993Xv9KVxQQmD7xI5FYEx9JmhwxayT3mkIST1JogUkqC
Decrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - Send 1000$ to Maarten and Artjom
Decrypted String with initVector: 'encryx|ninIntVec' - Send 9876$ to Maarten and Artjom
```

So please **do not use CBC-mode encryption and try to use GCM-mode or other authenticated modes** where ever it is possible!
B.t.w.: this called "tampering".

My code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MainTampering {
    private static final String key = "aesEncryptionKey";
    private static String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));
            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String originalString = "Send 1000$ to Maarten and Artjom";
        System.out.println("Original String to encrypt - " + originalString);
        String encryptedString = encrypt(originalString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - " + encryptedString);

        String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("Decrypted String with initVector: 'encryptionIntVec' - " + decryptedString);
        //output: "Send 1000$ to Maarten"

        // here the attacker changes the initVector without knowledge of the encryptionKey
        String guessedOrder = "Send 1000$ to Ma";
        String newOrder = "Send 9876$ to Ma";
        byte[] initvectorOrgByte = "encryptionIntVec".getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] initvectorByte = new byte[initvectorOrgByte.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            initvectorByte[i] = (byte) (initvectorOrgByte[i] ^ newOrder.getBytes("UTF-8")[i]
                    ^ guessedOrder.getBytes("UTF-8")[i]);
        }
        initVector = new String(initvectorByte);

        //initVector = "encryptionIntVec";
        String decryptedString2 = decrypt(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("Decrypted String with initVector: '" + initVector + "' - " + decryptedString2);
        //output: "Send 9876$ to Maarten"
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for the explanation, I'll try to use AES-GCM instead where ever it is possible